# Structuring ruby multidimensional hash by first hash

Tags: ruby, arrays, data-structures, hash

I have the hash below:

```
mm = {
    0 => {
        0 => 'p1',
        1 => 'p2',
        2 => 'p3'
    },
    1 => {
        0 => 'idfp1',
        1 => 'idfp2',
        2 => 'idfp3'
    },
    2 => {
        0 => 'idfp12',
        1 => 'idfp22',
        2 => 'idfp32'
    }
}
```

And i'm trying to sort it by the hash with a key of 0.  In the first hash (0), there are k-v pairs of number to identifier.

In every subsequent hash (1 and 2), 0 points to the 0 from the first hash, 1 points to the 1 from the first hash, etc.

In each hash after 0 (1 and 2), there are IDs (id for person 1) that belong to p1 (person 1).

I've tried to sort this by creating a new hash with only the first hash in the one above to no avail.  This is my attempt.  The keys are correct but it's pointing to `nil`, when it should be pointing to the hash with each person's id.

```
    ids = {}
    org = {}

    mm[0].each do |id, name|
        ids[id] = name
    end

    mm.drop(1).each do |one|
        one.each do |key, id|
            org[ids[key]] = id
        end
    end
```

How can I achieve this in Ruby?

Edit:

In case the explanation doesn't suffice, here is the desired result:

```
org = {
  'p1' => {
    0 => 'idfp1',
    1 => 'idfp12'
  },
  'p2' => {
    0 => 'idfp2',
    1 => 'idfp22'
  },
  'p3' => {
    0 => 'idfp3',
    1 => 'idfp32'
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two ways:

**#1**

*Code*

```
mm[0].invert.each_with_object({}) { |(k,i),h|
  h[k] = (1...mm.size).each_with_object ({}) { |j,g| g[j] = mm[j][i] } } 
  #=> {"p1"=>{1=>"idfp1", 2=>"idfp12"},
  #    "p2"=>{1=>"idfp2", 2=>"idfp22"},
  #    "p3"=>{1=>"idfp3", 2=>"idfp32"}}
```

*Explanation*

```
a = mm[0]
  #=> {0=>"p1", 1=>"p2", 2=>"p3"}
b = a.invert
  #=> {"p1"=>0, "p2"=>1, "p3"=>2}
b.each_with_object({}) { |(k,i),h|
  h[k] = (1...mm.size).each_with_object ({}) { |j,g| g[j] = mm[j][i] } } 
  #=> {"p1"=>{1=>"idfp1", 2=>"idfp12"},
  #    "p2"=>{1=>"idfp2", 2=>"idfp22"},
  #    "p3"=>{1=>"idfp3", 2=>"idfp32"}}
```

**#2**

*Code*

```
mm.values
  .map(&:values)
  .transpose
  .each_with_object({}) { |a,h| h[a.shift] = Hash[[*(0...a.size)].zip(a) ] }
  #=> {"p1"=>{0=>"idfp1", 1=>"idfp12"},
  #    "p2"=>{0=>"idfp2", 1=>"idfp22"},
  #    "p3"=>{0=>"idfp3", 1=>"idfp32"}}
```

*Explanation*

```
a = mm.values
  #=> [{0=>"p1",     1=>"p2",     2=>"p3"    },
  #    {0=>"idfp1",  1=>"idfp2",  2=>"idfp3" },
  #    {0=>"idfp12", 1=>"idfp22", 2=>"idfp32"}] 
b = a.map(&:values
  #=> [[   "p1",        "p2",        "p3"    ],
  #    [   "idfp1",     "idfp2",     "idfp3" ],
  #    [   "idfp12",    "idfp22",    "idfp32"]] 
c = b.transpose
  #=> [["p1", "idfp1", "idfp12"],
  #    ["p2", "idfp2", "idfp22"],
  #    ["p3", "idfp3", "idfp32"]]
c.each_with_object({}) { |a,h| h[a.shift] = Hash[[*(0...a.size)].zip(a) ] }
  #=> {"p1"=>{0=>"idfp1", 1=>"idfp12"},
  #    "p2"=>{0=>"idfp2", 1=>"idfp22"},
  #    "p3"=>{0=>"idfp3", 1=>"idfp32"}}
```

Comment: You can also substitute `Hash[[*(0...a.size)].zip(a) ]` with `a.size.times.zip(a).to_h` or `a.each_with_index.to_h.invert` which is even more "streamy"

Comment: @rewritten, good points, and a reminder to the reader that `Array#to_h` was introduced in Ruby 2.0. When I first saw the question, `Hash#invert` came to mind, but I did not immediately see how it might be used. Your reference to the method prompted me to rethink that, and I've added an alternative approach ("#1") that uses it, though not in the way you suggested.